# Need Django Query optimization (2 Queries instead of 21)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I have a Django project on EBS and one method that returns a QuerySet of `Article` objects takes a pretty long time. I'd like to optimize it so that it's just one or two queries but I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Models: `WebSite`,`Article`

The query is a list of `Articles` from different websites.

`WebSite` model has a `home_order` and `home_article_count` attributes that are used to select a number of articles and in which order they are.

Example for websites A, B and C:

1. `A` - `A.home_order = 2`, `A.home_article_count=3`
2. `B` - `B.home_order = 1`, `B.home_article_count=5`
3. `C` - `C.home_order = 3`, `C.home_article_count=7`

The result would be (aA means an article from website A):

**aB,aB,aB,aB,aB,aA,aA,aA,aC,aC,aC,aC,aC,aC,aC**

The lists starts with `aB` that means articles from website `B` because `B.home_order=1`, there are 5 `aB` articles as `B.home_article_count=5`.

Right now, this is a `Manager` method that returns the articles:

```
def home(self) -> QuerySet:
    articles_pks = []
    for ws in WebSite.objects.active().order_by('home_order', 'name'):
        articles_pks.extend(ws.articles.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-created')[:ws.home_article_count].values_list('pk',flat=True))
    return self.get_queryset().filter(pk__in=articles_pks)
```

That means, for 20 WebSite objects, there is 21 queries (one that gets the websites and the other 20 for articles).

Is it possible to merge it into one or two queries while respecting the `WebSite.home_order` and `WebSite.home_article_count`?

Comment: Is this the whole code for home? `return self.get_queryset().filter(pk__in=articles_pks)` doesn't care about the order or did you just remove some code to make it short?

Comment: @bdbd It's the whole code, thanks for the notification.

Comment: So far it looks like old the ordering is cancelled with `self.get_queryset().filter(pk__in=articles_pks)`. Is that intended?

Comment: @bdbd No it isn't intended but I can sort it then in memory, that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to combine the querysets using [`OR |`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#or) operator:

```py
def home(self) -> QuerySet:
    articles_pks = Article.objects.none()
    for ws in WebSite.objects.active().order_by('home_order', 'name'):
        articles_pks = articles_pks | ws.articles.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-created')[:ws.home_article_count]
    return self.get_queryset().filter(pk__in=articles_pks.values_list('pk',flat=True)))
```

You should end up with just two queries, one to get the websites and one for building and using the article list.